# Character substitution in file based on position extracted from another file

Tags: arrays, awk, string-substitution

I have a list of files each containing six lines. A representative example is shown below.

```
cat test.fa
>chain A
MIRLGAPQTLVLLTLLVAAVLRCQGQDVQEAGSCVQDGQRYNDKDVWKPEPCRICVCDTGTVLCDDIICEDVKDCLSPEIPFGECCPICPTDLATASGQPGPKGQKGEPGDIKDIVGPKGPPGPQGPAGEQGPRGDRGDKGEKGAPGPRGRDGEPGTPGNPGPPGPPGPPGPPGLGGNFAAQMAGGFDEKAGGAQLGVMQGPMGPMGPRGPPGPAGAPGPQGFQGNPGEPGEPGVSGPMGPRGPPGPPGKPGDDGEAGKPGKAGERGPPGPQGARGFPGTPGLPGVKGHRGYPGLDGAKGEAGAPGVKGESGSPGENGSPGPMGPRGLPGERGRTGPAGAAGARGNDGQPGPAGPPGPVGPAGGPGFPGAPGAKGE
>chain B
MMSFVQKGSWLLLALLHPTIILAQQEAVEGGCSHLGQSYADRDVWKPEPCQICVCDSGSVLCDDIICDDQELDCPNPEIPFGECCAVCPQPPTAPTRPPNGQGPQGPKGDPGPPGIPGRNGDPGIPGQPGSPGSPGPPGICESCPTGPQNYSPQYDSYDVKSGVAVGGLAGYPGPAGPPGPPGPPGTSGHPGSPGSPGYQGPPGEPGQAGPSGPPGPPGAIGPSGPAGKDGESGRPGRPGERGLPGPPGIKGPAGIPGFPGMKGHRGFDGRNGEKGETGAPGLKGENGLPGENGAPGPMGPRGAPGERGRPGLPGAAGARGNDGARGSDGQPGPPGPPGTAGFPGSPGAKGEVGPAGSPGSNGAPGQRGEPGPQGH
>chain C
MLPQIPFLLLVSLNLVHGVFYAERYQMPTGIKGPLPNTKTQFFIPYTIKSKGIAVRGEQGTPGPPGPAGPRGHPGPSGPPGKPGYGSPGLQGEPGLPGPPGPSAVGKPGVPGLPGKPGERGPYGPKGDVGPAGLPGPRGPPGPPGIPGPAGISVPGKPGQQGPTGAPGPRGFPGEKGAPGVPGMNGQKGEMGYGAPGRPGERGLPGPQGPTGPSGPPGVGKRGENGVPGQPGIKGDRGFPGEMGPIGPPGPQGPPGERGPEGIGKPGAAGAPGQPGIPGTKGLPGAPGIAGPPGPPGFGKPGLPGLKGERGPAGLPGGPGAKGEQGPAGLPGKPGLTGPPGNMGPQGPKGIPGSHGLPGPKGETGPAGPAGYPGAK
```

Reading row-by-row another file called test.list, I would like to substitute character position 140 in chain A of test.fa with "0" if the third column is "K" and character position 142 of chain B with "1" if the fourth column is E. Same for other rows.

```
cat test.list

A-B 140-142 K E
B-C 140-142 K E
A-B 299-301 K E
B-C 299-301 K E
```

I cannot figure out how to get a headstart. Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you clarify a couple of points as I'm a little confused. The files exemplified by `test.fa` all have 6 lines each and they are to be processed sequentially? Is `test.list` many more lines than the 4 shown, sufficient to process all the set of sequence files? Which row number of `test.list` is to be used for chain A in the first file, and which row for chain B? Presumably some lines not shown in `test.list` have values other than K and E?

Comment: Regarding `I would like to substitute character position 140` - don't post questions where we have to count 140+ characters, come up with an example where you want to substitute character position 4 or something. Any time you post a question where we need a scroll bar to read the example, you'll immediately discourage many people from being willing to try to help you. Also, add the expected output.

Comment: @DavePritlove: Correct! Each file has 6 lines to be processed one after the other.  Each test.fa has an associated test.list file. So, there are equal number of .fa and .list files. All rows that have A, B or C are to be processed. So the substitution will occur in all chains. Each row in the .list file will do two substitutions, corresponding to the chain and number before dash and also chain and number after the dash. Every line in the .list file is either K or E. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: @Jalan thanks, so, if I've understood correctly, each test.list specifies 8 substitutions, 2 applied to chain A, 2 applied to chain C, and 4 applied to chain B for the corresponding test.fa file?

Comment: @Jalan a further question - are fields 3 and 4 test.list always K and E respectively, and are the substitutions always to replace the numbered position with "0" and "1" respectively? What other alternatives exist... blank fields for no substitution? I don't get why the conditions K and E are needed.

Comment: @DavePritlove: Yes, 8 substitutions in total. Fields 3 and 4 are always K and E. The substitution is always to replace with 0 or 1. No alternative substitutions. Character position 140 in chain A is "K" and character position 142 in chain B is "E".

Comment: @Jalan do **both** conditions on each line of test.list have to met for **either** substitution to be made? Or should a substitution go ahead if the condition for its chain is met but the condition for the paired chain is not met? e.g. If there was a line in the condition file like `A-B 140-142 K L` the condition for chain A is met because position 140 of chain A is currently K, but the condition for chain B is not met because position 142 of chain B is E (not L). In such circumstances would the chain A '0' substitution go ahead with chain B being left alone, or would neither change be wanted?

Comment: Maybe using L was a bad idea in that last query. If it was E but position 142 in chain B was not E would the substitution for chain A (where 140 is currently K) go ahead?

Comment: @DavePritlove: Apologies for the late response. Weekend and all. Both conditions must be met for the substitutions to go ahead. The substitution should only happen if the position is occupied by K or E. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: @Jalan  I have a working procedure that I'll post later today when I get a few minutes to clean it up and annotate it to explain the steps. The basic procedure processes files in pairs named manually but, provided each .fa has the same prefix as its corresponding .list file (e.g. test.fa and test.list as in yor case) feeding files into the procedure could be automated. It will probably also need to make a log file if you have more than a few pairs of files.

Comment: @Jalan sorry for the delay, debugging took a little while longer than anticipated. I've tried to annotate my answer with sufficient  explanation for you to modify it to your needs. The posted script works for structure of the files as I've interpretted them but you may need to tweak it if things are not quite as I interpretted them.

Comment: @DavePritlove:Thank you for your awesome effort and very elegant description. Debugging a little based on my specific requirement. Will post a response soon.

Comment: @DavePritlove The write to out put file is not working. 

I think the problem is somewhere here.  

`for (indx in chains) {  
 print ">chain "indx"\n"chains[indx] >> outPath"modified_"fileID;  
 }  
`  
awk complains about it,  

`awk: syntax error at source line 60  
 context is  
  print ">chain "indx"\n"chains[indx] >> >>>  outPath"modified_" <<< fileID;  
awk: illegal statement at source line 60  
`

Comment: @Jalan That's strange, I don't get that error (I'm running GNU bash, version 5.1.16 , GNU Awk 5.2.0, on Terminal in Mac). Did the 'output' directory get created inside the target directory and did it contain the log file? If the log file was written, did it contain the information derived from awk (the list following 'results follow:' in the log file)? Judging by the position of the error, the log file should be written but your awk is not properly forming the path for the modified sequence files. You could try replacing `outPath"modified_"fileID` with `basename"output/modified_"fileID`.

Comment: @DavePritlove: Same error. I am running GNU bash, version 3.2.57, awk version 20200816, all in terminal on Mac (v12.4). The output directory and logfile is created but stops after matching the .list and .fa files. If I delete the lines throwing error, the script runs fine and the log file contains matches sequence positions but of course no output files are created.

Comment: @DavePritlove: I tried to debug but failed. The problem seems to come from how fileID is stored in the array in   ```# get .fa identified from file path;  
    n = split(FILENAME, a, "/");  
    fileID = a[n];  
    outPath = basename"output/"; # path to save output .fa files; ```  .

Comment: @Jalan sorry, I've been away for a couple of days but will try and have a look again tomorrow. let me know if you make any progress, I'm a little puzzled but it may become clear with a few experiments.

Comment: @DavePritlove: No worries. I showed it some people around me and they are equally perplexed. All looks in order. Somehow the fileID variable in awk block is not properly assigned which throws up the error.

Comment: @Jalan, I can't reproduce the error but have an idea to try as I think the error might occur because of using a concatenated file name directly in `print ">chain "indx"\n"chains[indx] >> outPath"modified_"fileID;` Instead, preform the sequence output filename at the top of the END block (after the lines assigning `fileID` and `outPath`) by adding `outSeqFile = outPath"modified_"fileID;` and then modify the sequence print line to `print ">chain "indx"\n"chains[indx] >> outSeqFile;`.

Comment: @DavePritlove: Woohoo!! Success! Thanks. It was indeed the concatenated file name passed to print. I wonder why though. If I write an awk one-liner to test, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Jalan Excellent, thanks for letting me know. very interesting and useful to know. It dealt with the concatenation without error on my system but as the error was reporting that line it was worth a try. Live and learn. Glad you got things working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Interpretation of the task**

Files are to be processed in pairs where a file with file-extension `.list` contains information needed to modify a corresponding file with file-extension `.fa`.

The `.fa` files contain `fasta`-formatted sequences for three chains identified A, B, or C. *I have assumed every `.fa` file will contain three sequences identified A, B, and C.* (if other identifiers are used, the script will need to be modified to extract identifiers for the chains).

The `.list` files contain four sets of conditions specifying changes to be made to the identified chains in the corresponding `.fa` file. Any changes *accumulate* as each condition is processed. Each condition is formatted as follows:

```
A-B 140-142 K E
```

Using the values in the above (one of four per pair of files) condition example, the instructions become:

> If position **140** in chain **A** (of the corresponding `.fa` file) is currently **K**

> **AND** If position **142** in chain **B** (of the corresponding `.fa` file) is currently **E**

> **PROVIDED BOTH CONDITIONS ARE MET** change position **140** in chain **A** to a `0` *AND* change position **142** in chain **B** to `1`.

> If only one (or no) condition is met, make no change. The changes will always be `0` for the first position and `1` for the second position.

The changed chains are then subjected to tests for the next three condition sets pertaining to that sequence file, accumulating changes with each condition set.

**Approach**

Since many paired files may exist, a `bash script` can be used to interrogate a `directory` containing target files to identify *pairs* of *matched* files to be processed. The target directory will be passed as an argument to the script.

The bash script will then pass pairs of matched files to an `awk` script, embedded in the `bash script`, where the values of the `.list` file can be read and the corresponding changes made to the `.fa` files.

Because of the potential for unforeseen errors, the original `.fa` files are not overwritten. Instead files containing the substituted sequences will be written to a set of new files (in a `sub-directory` of the target directory).

In order to track the changes and report any unmatched files, the script will also create a `log file` to record the changes made to each file and note any unmatched files.

**`awk` steps**

The `bash script` passes the `.list` file to `awk` *before* the corresponding `.fa` sequence file. Thus, when the **record number** `NR` (equivalent to accumulated line numbers across both files but beginning with the `.list` file) is equal to the **record number of the *current* file** `FNR`, the script is processing the first file and an action block can be assigned to perform steps only on the data in the `.list` file. Using this, the conditions data (in the `.list` file) can be re-formatted into an array for easier reading later on:

```
# this block only executes for lines in the first argument file (the .list file) because it has the condition pattern NR==FNR;
NR==FNR{
  split($1,abc,"-"); # splits e.g 'A-B' into an array named 'abc' with 'A' index 1, and 'B' in index 2;
  split($2,nums,"-"); # splits e.g '140-142' into an array named 'nums' with '140' index 1, and '142' in index 2;

conditions[NR,1] = abc[1];
conditions[NR,2] = abc[2];
conditions[NR,3] = nums[1];
conditions[NR,4] = nums[2];
conditions[NR,5] = $3; # $3 is e.g. 'K';
conditions[NR,6] = $4; # $4 is e.g. 'E';
conditions[NR,7] = $0; # the whole line;
}
```

(the comment note examples relate to the example condition `A-B 140-142 K E` as used above). A 2-d array named `conditions` is built containing the data needed for the tests later on.

A set of three pairs of short blocks follow. These extract the sequence runs for the three chains A, B, and C, storing them in an associative array indexed with the relevant letter. The first of each pair identifies the *record* (line) number `FNR` of the line following the line in which the chain identifier is found, storing it in a variable named `aline`, `bline` or `cline` for the three chains in each `.fa` file:

```
/>chain A/ {aLine = FNR+1}
FNR==aLine {chains["A"] = $0}
/>chain B/ {bLine = FNR+1}
FNR==bLine {chains["B"] = $0}
/>chain C/ {cLine = FNR+1}
FNR==cLine {chains["C"] = $0;}
```

When the line after the line containing the label, for example 'chain A', is encountered (`FNR==aLine`) the sequence found in that line is recorded in the `chains` array.

The condition tests and substitutions are made entirely in the `awk` `END` block, which executes once after the earlier blocks have been applied to each record (line) of the argument files.

The `END` block contains a loop to cycle through each condition, making any specified changes before moving to the next condition.

The logic test is performed inside the loop using an `if` conditional, which specifies that both conditions specified in the current condition line if the block of code is to be executed.

```
if (substr(chains[conditions[i,1]],conditions[i,3],1)==conditions[i,5] && substr(chains[conditions[i,2]],conditions[i,4],1)==conditions[i,6]) { # execute of both condition met;}
```

The right hand side of each comparison refers to the condition letter 'K' or 'E' from the earlier example, checking if it is currently present at the position specified in the left hand side of the condition. The current character at that position is extracted from the sequence, stored in `chains[conditions[i,1]]` (which resolves to chain array elements e.g `chains[A]` or `chains[B]`) using `awk`'s `substr` function to extract the single character present at position `condition[i,3]`.

If both conditions are met, the substitutions are made by joining `substr`s of the regions flanking the target position either side of the required '0' or '1'. The sequences, altered or not, are then written to file.

**Implementing the script**

The target files, one `.list` file for each `.fa`, file should be placed together in a directory. The directory name will be the argument for the script. The name part of the filenames should match for the matched pairs (e.g `sequence1.fa` should have a matched conditions file named `sequence1.list`).

(assuming the script is saved in a file named `process_list_fa.sh`). The script must be made executable. This can be done on the command line using:

```
chmod +x process_list_fa.sh
```

The script is then called from the command line as follows:

```
./process_list_fa.sh path/to/directory
```

The `path/to/directory` argument must represent the directory under which the matched files are stored. (don't use a trailing '/').

The script will execute, reporting progress to the command line. It may halt if, for example, the number of .fa files is different to the number of .list files, and await confirmation to continue.

Once complete, the target directory will now contain a sub directory named `output`. Inside the `output` directory will be a collection of files containg the modified sequences. Each will be named as it was originally but pre-pended with `modified_`. A `log.txt` file is also created summarising the changes made, and any files skipped. This may be useful for checking the files, especially if large numbers of pairs are processed.

**The `process_list_fa.sh` script**

copy the entire following snippet and save in a file named `process_list_fa.sh`. Make the file executable (`chmod +x process_list_fa.sh`) and execute it passing the directory containing the sequences as an argument (`./process_list_fa.sh path/directory`)

```
#!/bin/bash

# check for target directory passed as argument;
baseDir=$1;
if [ ! -d "$baseDir" ]; then
  echo "target directory $baseDir not found. exiting";
  exit;
fi

outputDir=$baseDir/output;
if [ ! -d "$outputDir" ]; then
  mkdir $outputDir;
fi

logFile=$outputDir/log.txt;

echo "directory: "$baseDir"/" > $logFile;
echo "results will be stored in: "$outputDir >> $logFile;
echo "checking for .fa and .list files inside $baseDir..."
skipCount=0;
skippedFiles=(); # array to store skipped file names in;

for FILE in $baseDir/*.fa; do 
#faCount=(( $faCount +1 ));
((faCount++));
done;

for FILE in $baseDir/*.list; do 
((listCount++));
done;

echo $faCount ".fa files found" >> $logFile;
echo $listCount ".list files found" >> $logFile;

echo $faCount ".fa files found, and " $listCount ".list files found";

if [ $faCount == $listCount ]; then
  echo "beginning replacement procedure..."; 
else 
  echo "WARNING - file numbers not equal";
  echo "if you choose to continue, unmatched files will be skipped";

  while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to continue? [y/n]" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo "results follow:" >> $logFile;
                echo "" >> $logFile;
                break;;
        [Nn]* ) echo "exiting... bye";
                echo "process quit by user" >>  $outputDir/log.txt;
                exit;;
        * ) echo "Please type y (continue) or n (exit).";;
    esac
  done;
fi

processCount=1;
ext=".list"

for FILE in $baseDir/*.fa; do 
listFile=${FILE/.fa/$ext};
# does the .list file exist?
if [ ! -f "$listFile" ]; then
  echo "Warning: no matched .list file for $FILE found. Skipping $FILE";
  #echo "" >> $logFile;
  #echo "No matched .list file for $FILE found. skipping $FILE" >> $logFile;
  ((skipCount++));
  skippedFiles+=($FILE); # append to array;
  continue;
fi

echo "file number "$processCount $FILE;
echo "matched list file: "$listFile "found";
echo "processing files "$FILE " and "$listFile;
echo "" >> $logFile;
echo "matched pair $processCount: " $FILE " and "$listFile >> $logFile;
((processCount++));

#### awk script ####

awk '
BEGIN {numConditionSets=0;}

NR==FNR{
numConditionsSets++;

# organise conditions data into an array;
  split($1,abc,"-");
  split($2,nums,"-");

conditions[NR,1] = abc[1];
conditions[NR,2] = abc[2];
conditions[NR,3] = nums[1];
conditions[NR,4] = nums[2];
conditions[NR,5] = $3;
conditions[NR,6] = $4;
conditions[NR,7] = $0; # the whole line;


# make path to pre-existing log file;
  if (NR==1) {
    n = split(FILENAME, a, "/");
      for (i=1; i<n; i++) {basename=basename a[i]"/";}
    logFile = basename"output/log.txt";
  } # end 1st line block;
} # end NR==FNR block;


# store chains in chains array;
/>chain A/ {aLine = FNR+1}
FNR==aLine {chains["A"] = $0}
/>chain B/ {bLine = FNR+1}
FNR==bLine {chains["B"] = $0}
/>chain C/ {cLine = FNR+1}
FNR==cLine {chains["C"] = $0;}


END {

# get .fa identified from file path;
    n = split(FILENAME, a, "/");
    fileID = a[n];
    outPath = basename"output/"; # path to save output .fa files;

# loop conditions, mutating sequences along the way;

for (i=1; i<=numConditionsSets; i++) {

  if (substr(chains[conditions[i,1]],conditions[i,3],1)==conditions[i,5] && substr(chains[conditions[i,2]],conditions[i,4],1)==conditions[i,6]) { 

       chains[conditions[i,1]] = substr(chains[conditions[i,1]],1,conditions[i,3]-1)"0"substr(chains[conditions[i,1]],conditions[i,3]+1);
       chains[conditions[i,2]] = substr(chains[conditions[i,2]],1,conditions[i,4]-1)"1"substr(chains[conditions[i,2]],conditions[i,4]+1);
print "condition "i" ("conditions[i,7]"): chain "conditions[i,1]" residue "conditions[i,3]" "conditions[i,5]" to 0, chain "conditions[i,2]" residue "conditions[i,4]" "conditions[i,6]" to 1," >> logFile;

     } else {print "condition "i" ("conditions[i,7]"): not met, no changes made," >> logFile;}
} # next i condition set;


  for (indx in chains) {
    print ">chain "indx"\n"chains[indx] >> outPath"modified_"fileID;
  } 
 

} # end END block;





' $listFile $FILE 


done; # end for-in-do;

#### log unmatched/skipped .fa files ######
echo "" >> $logFile; 
echo "${#skippedFiles[@]} .fa files were unmatched with .list files and skipped:" >> $logFile;

for i in "${skippedFiles[@]}"
do
   echo "$i" >> $logFile;
done

echo "" >> $logFile;
echo "END" >> $logFile;
```